# Traverse through List<List <Opportunity>> (multi-dimension)

Tags: apex, list, loop

I have a  `List<List<Opportunity>> totalMpRecords`

I want to be able to extract all the Opportunties in each of those Lists and put them in one main List.

This seems pretty straightforward, yet I cannot figure out how to do this efficiently. The following does not compile:

```
//List<List <Opportunity>> totalMpRecords
//List<Opportunity> finalListOpps
      for(Opportunity opp : totalMpRecords){
        for(Opportunity innerList : opp.Opportunities){
          finalListOpps.add(innerList);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're close to the solution.

The thing that you're getting caught on is that the outer loop isn't iterating over a single `Opportunity`, but rather a `List<Opportunity>`

```
// Outer loop on a List<List<Opportunity>> gets you one level in, resulting in
//   a List<Opportunity>
for(List<Opportunity> oppList : totalMpRecords){
    // Inner loop works on each List<Opportunity>, giving you the individual
    //   Opportunities.
    for(Opportunity innerList : oppList){
      finalListOpps.add(innerList);
    }
  }
```

+edit:

A slightly different way to approach this, while eliminating the inner loop from your code would be to use `List.addAll()`, which can take a list, and add all of its elements to another list.

```
for(List<Opportunity> oppList : totalMpRecords){
    finalListOpps.addAll(oppList);
}
```

If we could dig into the implementation of `addAll()`, it'd probably contain a `for` loop of its own, so there's not likely any noticeable performance difference between the two. Dealing with nested structures is often an O(n^2) affair.

Comment: It could be even cleaner if you remove the inner loop and do finalListOpps.addAll(oppList) to add all of the inner list elements at once.

Comment: @JohnTowers Indeed. I was just making my edit when you commented.